# Elasticity of a Strictly Concave Function

Tags: calculus

I have a strictly increasing concave function $G(E)$ such that $G'(E) > 0$ and $G''(E) < 0$. Is is necessary in general for elasticity of $G(E)$ with respect to $E$ to be less than $1$
*i.e.* $G'(E)\frac{E}{G(E)} < 1$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Consider $G(E)=\ln(E)$.